Ground state energy: Spin vs Fermionic language
Background
Consider the Hamiltonian of 1D periodic Ising model given by
$$ \hat{H}_{\mathrm{PBC}} = -J\sum_{i=1}^L X_i X_{i+1} - h\sum_{i=1}^L Z_i, $$
where $X_i$ and $Z_i$ are Pauli operators.
Now, introduce Jordan-Wigner transformation
$$ 
\begin{align}
X_i &= K_i(c_i^\dagger + c_i), \\
Z_i &= 1-2c_i^\dagger c_i \equiv 1-2n_i,
\end{align}
$$
with $K_i = \prod_{j=1}^{i-1}\exp(i\pi n_j)$.
Since $\hat{H}_{\mathrm{PBC}}$ commutes with the parity operator $\hat{\mathcal{P}} = \prod_{i=1}^L Z_i = \prod_{i=1}^L \exp{(i\pi n_i)}$, $\hat{H}_{\mathrm{PBC}}$ is block-diagonalized based on $\hat{\mathcal{P}}$'s eigenvalues as $\hat{H}_{\mathrm{PBC}} = \hat{H}_0 \oplus \hat{H}_1 $.
By defining the following Hamiltonian
$$
\hat{\mathbb{H}}_p = -J\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}(c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} + c_i^\dagger c_{i+1}^\dagger +\mathrm{h.c.})
+ J(-1)^p(c_L^\dagger c_1 + c_L^\dagger c_1^\dagger+\mathrm{h.c.})
+ h\sum_{i=1}^L (2n_j - 1),
$$
the block-Hamiltonian is expressed as $\hat{H}_p = \hat{\mathbb{H}}_p P_p $ where $P_{0/1}$ corresponds to a projector onto eigenspace of the parity operator $\hat{\mathcal{P}}$ with eigenvalue $\pm1$.
Here, $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_0$ corresponds to a fermionic Hamiltonian under anti-periodic boundary condition (APBC), while $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_1$ corresponds to a fermionic Hamiltonian under PBC.
The above discussion implies that the full energy spectrum of the original spin-Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_{\mathrm{PBC}}$ can be reconstructed from the energy spectrum of the even parity subspace of APBC-fermion-Hamiltonian $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_0$ and the odd parity subspace of PBC-fermion-Hamiltonian $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_1$.
Let $G_p$ be the single-particle Hamiltonian s.t. $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_p = \Psi^\dagger G_p \Psi$, with $\Psi = (c_1\cdots c_L,c_1^\dagger, \cdots, c_L^\dagger)^T$, and let $\{\epsilon_{p,\mu}\}_{\mu=1\cdots L}$ represent the non-negative single-particle energies of $G_p$.
Then, the energies of the original spin system is given by
$$
E_{p, \{n_\mu\}} = E_{p,0} + 2\sum_{\mu}n_{\mu}\epsilon_{p,\mu},\:\:\mathrm{with}
\:\:E_{p,0} = -\sum_{j=1}^L \epsilon_{p, \mu},\:\mathrm{and}
\:\:n_{\mu} = 0,1.
$$
I believe the discussion above is well-known and correct.
My question
I numerically checked whether the energy formula above holds true, but I failed to reproduce the expected result, especially for the parameter regions in the ordered phase ($h<1$).
I would like to know why.
What I did
Consider the case of $h=0$ for simplicity.
Then, the ground state is two-fold degenerate, and we can explicitly write them as
$$
|\psi_\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\cdots +\rangle \pm |-\cdots -\rangle),
$$
where $|\pm\rangle$ is the eigenstate of Pauli $X_i$ with eigenvalue $\pm1$.
Since the state $|\psi_+\rangle$ is an even parity state and $|\psi_-\rangle$ is an odd parity state, each energy should correspond to the even parity spectrum of $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_0$ and odd parity spectrum of $\hat{\mathbb{H}}_1$, respectively.
Specifically, we set $L=4$, $J=1$, $h=0$ for instance.
First I constructed Ising Hamiltonian and diagonalize it to obtain the ground state energy:
$$
E_0 = -4\:\:(\textrm{two-fold}\:\textrm{degenerate})
$$
Next, I constructed the single-particle Hamiltonian corresponding to the APBC-fermionic Hamiltonian, and diagonalize it to obtain its non-negative energies:
$$
\{\epsilon_{0,\mu}\} = \{1, 1, 1, 1\}
$$
Then, the lowest energy in the even parity sector is:
$$
E_{0,0} = -(1+1+1+1) = -4,
$$
which agrees with the ground state energy.
However, since the single-particle energies of PBC-fermionic Hamiltonian are also
$$
\{\epsilon_{1,\mu}\} = \{1, 1, 1, 1\},
$$
the lowest energy in the odd parity sector is:
$$
E_{1,0} = -(1+1+1+1) + 2\times1 = -2,
$$
which not only fails to match the ground state energy, but also does not appear in the full energy spectrum.
While this construction method doesn't work for all parameter regions in ordered phase ($h<1$), I found that it correctly reproduces the full spectrum in the disordered phase ($h\geq1$).

For $h=0.5$, the points consistent with the spin system energies are those of the even parity sector of APBC-fermionic Hamiltonian, while those of the odd parity sector of PBC-fermionic Hamiltonian deviate. On the other hand, for $h=2.0$, the formula perfectly reproduces the correct energies.
Related question & Reference
Ground state degeneracy: Spin vs Fermionic language
The quantum Ising chain for beginners

Your numerical results demonstrate the fact that the ground state of the fermionic Hamiltonian can have different parity depending on the parameters of the problem. For the Hamiltonian of the quantum Ising model we see here that for an even number of spins $N$, the ground state of the fermionic Hamiltonian corresponding to antiperiodic boundary conditions is always even, and for the fermionic Hamiltonian corresponding to periodic boundary conditions, the ground state is odd in the ordered phase, for $h < J$, and even in the disordered phase, for $h > J$. In particular, this means that when you consider the case $h=0$, you should not add $2$ to $-4$ when searching for the lowest energy in the odd parity sector. The change in the parity of the ground state at $h = J$ manifests itself in the presence of a zero eigenvalue in the single-particle Hamiltonian, which is absent at $h\neq J$. I am sure that this can be easily verified numerically. The effect of the parity change of the ground state of the fermion Hamiltonian is probably covered in sufficient detail in the literature, but I cannot provide the relevant references now. Most likely, it is not difficult to figure this out on your own.

Thank you for taking the time to consider my problem.
Could you clarify what you mean by "parity change of the ground state of the fermion Hamiltonian"? My understanding is that  the parity of a state with an eigenvalue $E_{{n_\mu}} = E_0 + \sum_\mu n_\mu \epsilon_\mu$ is determined by the parity of $\sum_\mu n_\mu$. That's why I added 2 to -4 for obtaining the lowest energy in the odd parity sector.
And, if the"parity change" like the one you mentioned were to occur, would it then be difficult to reconstruct the full energy spectrum from the single-particle energies a priori?

@Hio, In general case, parity in terms of new fermion operators does not coincide with the parity in terms of initial fermion operators, they can be opposite. You can easily see this in XX model, if you are familiar with it. I also don't see how the change of parity makes reconstruction of full energy spectrum difficult. And you can check my words by direct numerical computation. For $h < J$ just don't add one-particle energy to the lowest fermionic energy in the sector with PBC and see if it coincides with energy level of spin system.

@Hio, As you can solve many-particle problem numerically, then you even can construct the operator of parity in terms of initial operators and numerically compute how it acts on eigenvectors.

Finally, I understand you were completely right. The parity of the new fermions doesn’t always match that of the initial fermions, or equivalently, the original spin states. I’ve also figured out how to determine the ground state parity from the single-particle Hamiltonian. Following Kitaev's seminal paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010440), we first express the single-particle Hamiltonian in the Majorana basis and then check the sign of its Pfaffian. This reveals the ground state parity for a given set of parameters.
Thank you for guiding me to the solution.
